# Derivative function $\frac 1f$ in the sense of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

$\newcommand\interval{\mathopen]0,T\mathclose[}$Let $f \in W^{1,\infty }(\interval)$ and $f(x)>1$ a.e. $x\in \interval$.  Then $g = \frac 1f \in W^{1,\infty}(\interval)$. (g  is Lipschitz in $\interval$.)

I want to show it again by use derivative of g.

Is it reasonable to say that  $g'= \frac{-f '} {f^2}$ in $D'$?. If yes, I need a way to prove it

Comment: If $f\in W^{1,\infty}$ means that $f,f'\in L^\infty$ then (the $W^{1,\infty}$ class of) $f$ is represented by a continuous function $F$ so $f>1$ a.e. implies $F>1$ and hence $-F'/F^2$ is obviously the derivative of $1/F$.

Comment: @reuns  Why $F′/F^2$ is obviously the derivative of $1/F$. Do you apply chaine rule in Sobolev space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\phi \in C^\infty_c,\phi \ge 0, \int\phi=1$.

$F_n=F\ast n \phi(nx)$ is $C^\infty$ and it converges to $F$ locally uniformly.

Since $F>1$ then $\frac{1}{F_n}$ converges to $\frac1{F}$ uniformly.

And $\frac{-F_n'}{F_n^2}$ converges to $\frac{-F'}{F^2}$ in $D'$.

ie. $\frac{-F'}{F^2}$ is the distributional derivative of $\frac1{F}$.

In $D'$: $\frac{-F'}{F^2}=\frac{-f'}{f^2},\frac1{F}=\frac1f$.

Comment: Hmm ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I don't see why $F_n(x)\neq 0 \forall x$ if F>1

Comment: $*$ is a convolution.

Comment: $F_n>1$ when $\phi\ge 0$